# iOS Calendar: What is the meaning of Time Zone Override?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, settings, timezone

I have had issues in the past with time zones and alarms when traveling, but I think I have it solved. I have just one more point of confusion.

Current versions of iOS have the option `Time Zone Override` for the calendar. Mine is currently set to `Off`, which I think is the default. The setting can be found in `Settings > Calendar > Time Zone Override`

The question is: **What does the setting `Time Zone Override` actually mean?** Does it in any way affect events which have a time zone or are marked as floating.

More specifically, when I am in a different time zone, how does this setting affect the following possibilities:

- `Time Zone Override: Off`, Event time zone set to home
- `Time Zone Override: On`, Event time zone set to home
- `Time Zone Override: Off`, Event time zone set to floating
- `Time Zone Override: On`, Event time zone set to floating

Comment: What are floating events?

Comment: Floating events are those without a time zone, so they always appear in the currently local time.

Comment: Can you please give an example how to create an event with a floating time zone with iOS and/or macOS?`

Comment: @oa- In the MacOS Calender, I have time zone support turned on (Preferences/Advanced). Timed Events (not all-day) now have an extra setting for Time Zone. One of the options is Floating.

Answer (score 1):

**Floating events**

These kind of events happen **always at the same time of day**. An event called "Wake up" set for 6 AM and with the time zone set to Floating will always occur at 6 AM.

If you are in LA, it will occur at 6 AM, if you are in Hong Kong, it will also occur at 6 AM.

The time zone in `Settings > General > Date & Time` is relevant for floating events.

---

**Regular events** (Time Zone set to GMT+1 with DST)

You are in London and create an event "Process emails" for 4 PM (time zone set to London, GMT+1).

Turn on time zone override and set it to New York. Your event will now show up at 8 AM (GMT-4).

---

To answer your specific scenarios

- `Time Zone Override: Off`, Event time zone set to home

  > An event at 6 AM will be displayed at 6 AM
- `Time Zone Override: On`, Event time zone set to home

  > An event at 6 AM will be displayed at 1 AM (London to NY)
- `Time Zone Override: Off`, Event time zone set to floating

  > An event at 6 AM will always be displayed at 6 AM, no matter where you are.
- `Time Zone Override: On`, Event time zone set to floating

  > An event at 6 AM will always be displayed at 6 AM, no matter where you are.